# When should a point of order be raised for an error by the chair in calling a vote?

Tags: parliamentary-procedure, roberts-rules-of-order

Under Robert's Rules of Order, if the chair does not follow proper procedure in calling a vote, but the error does not influence the outcome (e.g. it passes with such an overwhelming majority that it it clear that it would have still passed under proper procedure), should a point of order be raised as soon as the mistake happens or after the vote is over?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### To be valid, a point of order generally needs to be made at the time of the possible Rules violation

Exceptions are where the Rules violation violates the law, where it conflicts with a previously adopted motion (other than a motion to rescind that earlier motion), or where it violates a [fundamental principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_parliamentary_procedure).

Assuming your example doesn’t do any of those things, then the point of order is moot once the vote has been taken.

Comment: very similar to courts:  Unless raised as soon as it happened or discovered, you can't appeal on such grounds